Is there any method to sort a range by the last edit date of each row in google sheets?
I have a table tracking projects that gets updated fairly often, but doesn't have a date column. While we do put the date in when the project is completed, we haven't been doing the same at every single status update.



Name
Misc. Data
Status




Adam
abcd
status a


Bart
xyoz
status b


Caroline
lmno
status c 10/12



New rows are constantly being added and the table is already quite large, so I can't individually go through each row, check the last edit date of each column, and add it to the status column to then be sorted. I want to know if there is a function that can do that for me, or alternatively just move the row to the top of the range when it is updated.

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Going forward, the easiest solution would be to add an automatic timestamp column. You may want to take a look at scripts such as my yetAnotherTimestamp_, timestampMultipleRanges_ and timestampMultipleColumns_. They're easier than moving rows up when they are updated.

To get last edit dates of existing data requires a bit of code, and I'm not sure this is the right site to request help with that. If you already have code that you'd like to fix or improve, you can try at [so]. Before you post there, see How do I ask a good question?
